# I have a tabular (40X7) research dataset including a target column, now how to create a new dataset following the same pattern of initial dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My tabular dataset consists of 40 rows and 7 columns, one of them is the target column. I want to make new dataset following the existing dataset patterns. For example, currently my dataset size is 40X7, I want to make it 200X7 using the same pattern. How can I do it using TensorFlow and Keras?

I am trying to apply Autoencoder and LSTM. Please suggest me a convenient way.

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far and provide a minimal reproducible example of input and expected output

Comment: that's all what I mentioned.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask] to undertake why your question does not fit for SO as it is stated .

Comment: For example, If the experimental data like
T=300 C, time= 60 min, Catalyst= Type A gives 70% biodiesel yield,  I want the ANN model to predict what the input parameters to achieve 90 or even 95% biodiesel yield?